# Analysing properties of a function in integral form

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

let:

$$F(x) = \int_0^x\sqrt{t}\sin(t)dt$$

Say whether $F(x)$ is positive, negative or zero at each of the following points, and give a reason in each case:

$$x = \pi$$
$$x = 2\pi$$

I was trying:

$$F'(x) = \sqrt{x}\sin(x)$$
$$F''(x) = \sqrt{x}\cos(x)+\sin(x)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

If we evaluate the second derivative at $\pi$ we see that we are at a local maximum is that enough reason to say that when we evaluate or function at $\pi$ is positive?

Comment: A remark: named functions like sine look nicer when you prepend a backslash. For example, `\sin x` gives $\sin x$ and `\ln x` gives $\ln x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since derivatives (and second derivatives) only give you the rates of change, we cannot usually directly determine very much about the function values at specific points (apart from certain special cases, such as the function value starting at $0$ and the derivative then always being positive meaning the value will always be positive after the starting point). Instead, here are a couple of alternate methods to solve your problem.

For $x = \pi$, since for $0 \lt t \lt \pi$ we have $\sqrt{t} \gt 0$ and $\sin(t) \gt 0$, then $F(\pi) \gt 0$ (note that, for this case, your result of $F'(x) = \sqrt{x}\sin(x)$ means that $F'(x) \gt 0$ for $0 \lt x \lt \pi$, so with $F(0) = 0$, this also shows that $F(\pi) \gt 0$).

With $x = 2\pi$, the second term in the third line below uses the substitution $y = 2\pi - t \;\;\to\;\; dy = -dt$, and then that $\sin(2\pi - y) = -\sin(y)$, to get that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
F(2\pi) & = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{t}\sin(t)dt \\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{t}\sin(t)dt + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\sqrt{t}\sin(t)dt \\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{t}\sin(t)dt + \int_{\pi}^{0}\sqrt{2\pi - y}\sin(2\pi - y)(-dy) \\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{t}\sin(t)dt - \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{2\pi - y}\sin(y)dy \\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{z}\sin(z)dz - \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{2\pi - z}\sin(z)dz \\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi}(\sqrt{z} - \sqrt{2\pi - z})\sin(z)dz
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

For $0 \lt z \lt \pi$, we get $z \lt 2\pi - z \;\;\to\;\; \sqrt{z} - \sqrt{2\pi - z} \lt 0$, with $\sin(z) \gt 0$ as mentioned earlier, so $F(2\pi) \lt 0$.

Comment: In line five second term:     $2\pi -y = t $therfore $\sqrt{2\pi-y} =\sqrt{t} $

Comment: can you explain what you did in line 5?

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts Note that the scope of the integration variables, e.g., $t$ or $y$, is just *within* the integration itself. In other words, they don't affect anything outside of that integration, such as other integrations (this is similar to, in programming, having local variables, say $y$ and $t$, within different functions, with them not affecting each other). Thus, they are just dummy variables that can be replaced by anything else, including reusing a previous variable name, e.g., $t$ in this case, which I did by replacing the $y$ with $t$ in the second term in line #$5$. ...

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts (cont.) This was to try to make it more clear that, with the limits also being the same, with the same integration variables, we can combine the $2$ integrations into one. However, as I now see that reusing $t$ can be confusing, I've changed my answer to change both $t$ and $y$ to a new $z$ dummy variable instead. I hope that this explanation, and answer update, helps to make things more clear.

Comment: Your computer programming analogy made me understand, I was confused because in integration by U substitution in the end you have to replace the U term